# How to load javascript in master page sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin

This is my js code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
var pngPath = '/_catalogs/masterpage/assets/tools-banner.jpg'; 
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.src = url + pngPath;
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Banner");
document.querySelector("#banner").appendChild(elem);

</script>
```

when i test it in the browser console it work just fine , but when i put it in the  of my master page it doesn't work
should i load jquery?
any solution ?

Comment: You must wait for the DOM to be loaded before executing the code, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Comment: where should i add the dom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you end the script with  tag? better copy your code in a text file ( remember not to add  tag in the text file, just the code) and save it as .js file. Load the file in Style library and publish it.

Now in Master page  add script tag  `<script type="text/javascript" src="link where javascript is loaded"></script>`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41817/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-kumar-how-to-load-javascript-in-master-page-sharep).